# JNA: __stdcall ESP corruption

Tags: c++, jna

While trying to get notification from C++ app through JNA callback, I constantly see JVM crashes.  Native.setProtected doesn't help.  The original callback declaration is

```
typedef void (__stdcall *TRANS2QUIK_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK) (long nMode, DWORD dwTransID, double dNumber, LPCSTR ClassCode, LPCSTR SecCode, double dPrice, long nBalance, double dValue, long nIsSell, long nStatus, long nOrderDescriptor);
```

**^^^ this is that doesn't work**

I tried both StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback which should work and simple Callback, they both failed.
But after I wrote C++ wrapper, where I just call JNA callback as cdecl from inside of original C++ stdcall callback, everything started to work smoothly.

```
typedef void (*WRAPPED_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK) (double dNumber, double dPrice, long nBalance, double dValue, long nIsSell, long nStatus, long nOrderDescriptor);  

QUIKWRAP_API TRANS2QUIK_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK __stdcall wrapCallback(WRAPPED_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK);
```

**^^^^^^ this is that works smoothly w/o problems**

The question could this be a JNA bug specifically for this function signature?
Because I have another stdcall callback in my code with different signature and it works just fine.

**I created an isolated testcase for this issue, see below**:
java

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.PointerType;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;


public class JNATest {
    interface TestCallback extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
        void testCallback(NativeLong nMode, WinDef.DWORD dwTransID, double dNumber, LPCSTR ClassCode, LPCSTR SecCode, double dPrice, NativeLong nBalance, double dValue, NativeLong nIsSell, NativeLong nStatus, NativeLong nOrderDescriptor);
    }

    interface JNADLL extends StdCallLibrary{
        void testCallback(TestCallback cb);
    }
    public static class LPCSTR extends PointerType {
        public LPCSTR(Pointer address) {
            super(address);
        }
        public LPCSTR() {
            super();
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getPointer().getString(0);
        }
    };



    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("jna.encoding", "Cp1251");

        HashMap<String, Object> nameMapping = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        nameMapping.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, StdCallLibrary.FUNCTION_MAPPER);
        nameMapping.put(Library.OPTION_CALLING_CONVENTION, StdCallLibrary.STDCALL_CONVENTION);

        JNADLL JNADll = (JNADLL) Native.loadLibrary("QuikWrap", JNADLL.class, nameMapping);

        TestCallback cb = new TestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void testCallback(NativeLong nMode, DWORD dwTransID,
                    double dNumber, JNATest.LPCSTR ClassCode, JNATest.LPCSTR SecCode,
                    double dPrice, NativeLong nBalance, double dValue,
                    NativeLong nIsSell, NativeLong nStatus, NativeLong nOrderDescriptor) {
                System.out.println("testCallback  \n" +
                        "  nMode: " + nMode + "\n" +
                        "  dwTransID: " + dwTransID + "\n" +
                        "  number: " + dNumber + "\n" +
                        "  ClassCode: " + ClassCode + "\n" +
                        "  SecCode: " + SecCode + "\n" +
                        "  price: " + dPrice + "\n" +
                        "  balance: " + nBalance + "\n" +
                        "  value: " + dValue + "\n" +
                        "  isSell: " + nIsSell + "\n" +
                        "  status: " + nStatus + "\n" +
                        "  orderDescriptor: " + nOrderDescriptor + "\n");
            }
        };
        JNADll.testCallback(cb);
    }

}
```

c header QuikWrap.h

```
#ifdef QUIKWRAP_EXPORTS
#define QUIKWRAP_API extern "C"__declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define QUIKWRAP_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
typedef void (__stdcall *TRANS2QUIK_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK) (long nMode, DWORD dwTransID, double dNumber, LPCSTR ClassCode, LPCSTR SecCode, double dPrice, long nBalance, double dValue, long nIsSell, long nStatus, long nOrderDescriptor);
QUIKWRAP_API void __stdcall testCallback(TRANS2QUIK_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK cb);
```

c source QuikWrap.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "QuikWrap.h"
#include "stdio.h"

QUIKWRAP_API void __stdcall testCallback(TRANS2QUIK_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK cb){
    cb(1, 2, 3, "Hi", "Bye", 4.0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    cb(0, 2, 3, "Hi", "Bye", 4.0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    return;
}
```

**the only output from callback I got is**

```
testCallback  
  nMode: 1
  dwTransID: 2
  number: 3.0
  ClassCode: Hi
  SecCode: Bye
  price: 4.0
  balance: 5
  value: 6.0
  isSell: 7
  status: 8
  orderDescriptor: 9
```

**then callback fails on exit**

Comment: It's possible there's a stdcall deficiency; I had to add stdcall callback support to libffi in order for JNA to support it.

Comment: thanks for answer, could you explain a bit, that deficiency you mean? as I know there is stdcall support in JNA already which works just fine for other method with different signature.

for instance, this one works smoothly
typedef void (__stdcall *TRANS2QUIK_TRANSACTION_REPLY_CALLBACK) (long nTransactionResult, long nTransactionExtendedErrorCode, long nTransactionReplyCode, DWORD dwTransId, double dOrderNum, LPCSTR lpcstrTransactionReplyMessage);

it contains same types of arguments but just 6 args instead of 11 in "bad" case.
could that be some array length limit in libffi?..

Comment: I am very glad to see an author of the project answering me, greetings Timothy!
BTW, I thinked more and decided I was wrong in suspecting array length. As long as all arguments passed to Java callback, forwarding part works just fine, the error is somethere about in cleanup part, I believe.

Comment: In your callback, make sure you cast all your arguments to their target types to eliminate any compiler-based type promotion from the equation.

Comment: Your original Java code indicates 11 arguments to the callback.  Your native test code only passes 9 arguments.  Turn up warnings in your compiler and you should get better feedback on errors of this nature.

Comment: Yes, original was 11 args and stdcall. To workaround I created wrapper, which only returns back 9 args using cdecl. This works. No problem. But in my JNA test I used 11 args with stdcall exacly like it was in original (w/o workaraund). It fails. The main difference from original is that in original I call 3rd party dll and in my test I call just a simple test I created by myself.
Please note that my test callback with 11 args and stdcall are able to get fired and receive data from C++, but after exit of JNA callback, JVM crashes. I use Oracle JVM 4 Win32 if that makes sence.

Comment: I changed C++ dll function to 
`QUIKWRAP_API void __stdcall testCallback(TRANS2QUIK_ORDER_STATUS_CALLBACK cb){
 //(long nMode, DWORD dwTransID, double dNumber, LPCSTR ClassCode, LPCSTR SecCode, double dPrice, long nBalance, double dValue, long nIsSell, long nStatus, long nOrderDescriptor);
 cb((long)10, (DWORD)2, (double)3, (LPCSTR)"Hi", (LPCSTR)"Bye", (double)4.0, (long)5, (double)6, (long)7, (long)8, (long) 9);
 cb((long)-10, (DWORD)2, (double)3, (LPCSTR)"Hi", (LPCSTR)"Bye", (double)4.0, (long)5, (double)6, (long)7, (long)8, (long) 9);
 return;
}`
as you recommended - added a type-cast

Comment: the result is the same:
`testCallback  
  nMode: 10
  dwTransID: 2
  number: 3.0
  ClassCode: Hi
  SecCode: Bye
  price: 4.0
  balance: 5
  value: 6.0
  isSell: 7
  status: 8
  orderDescriptor: 9`
and after that it fails with message that ESP was not a properly saved accross a function call

Comment: I set up a test case with the 9 argument version and the 11 argument version.  Both seem to have no problems (see StdCallCallback test case in W32StdCallTestCase).  I am compiling with gcc3, which may make a difference.

Comment: Interesting! I changed JNA to the argument types you used, don't touched dll, still same result, arguments passed, fails on return.
I use VC10 Express. 
Looking into your W32StdCallTest.java and native/testlib.c I don't see 11 args callback, only 9 args version. Could you please share your working testcase with 11 args?
9 args are also worked in my setup. The only problem is with 11 args method signature.

Comment: please have a look into QuikWrap.h and QuikWrap.cpp above for the code of native lib and 11 args method which fails being called from JNA
The difference between 9 and 11 args is in 2 more `double, long` args near 6th argument, should be something like
`interface BugCallback extends StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback {
            void callback(NativeLong arg1, int arg2, double arg3,
                          String arg4, String arg5, double arg6,
                          NativeLong arg7, double arg8,
                          NativeLong arg9, NativeLong arg10, NativeLong arg11);
        }`

Comment: The issue has been reproduced on [this branch](https://github.com/twall/jna/tree/issue-300) (see [`native/testlib.c`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/issue-300/native/testlib.c) and [`W32StdCallTest`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/issue-300/test/com/sun/jna/win32/W32StdCallTest.java).  Possibly something to do with a different `stdcall` behavior after a certain parameter list size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to a bug in `libffi`, where the stack alignment is being adjusted according to argument size, which is incorrect behavior for `stdcall`.